# What exactly IS the highlighted image in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

This question boggles my mind and I cannot find an answer. I looked all over the documentation, tried out code, and searched Google, but I can't find anything. The UIImageView in iOS programming can have an image set to it, but you can also set a highlighted image to it. What exactly is this highlighted image?

Answer (score 37):

you can set two different images to an UIImageView, one to its image property, another to its highlightedImage property.

There are many cases where you want to change the state of the image (eg: a checkmark) from off to on or vice versa. in that case, instead of you setting the UIImageView's image to the appropriate one everytime, you can just say

```
theCheckMarkImageView.image = regularImage;//set the regular image
theCheckMarkImageView.highLightedImage = highlightedImage;
```

(based on your logic show it highlighted or not).

```
theCheckMarkImageView.highlighted = YES/NO;
```

In addition to all this, do check Ethan Huang's answer about how tabelviewcell works with this property. Quite useful if you are showing different images based on cell selection.

Comment: hence it is alike UIButton's isEnabled property. good to know.
Thank you for explanation

Answer (score 8):

highlightedImage use for highlight ImageView,simple.

```
imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hightlighted.png"];
imageView.highlighted = YES;
```

Don't need to waste time to search or read a lot. Objective-C is meaningful language. Just drag ImageView and make a try code, step by step test all property, method in UIImageView.h(in UIKit framework) and you'll understand.
Do the same with other UI element.

Comment: "Objective-C is meaningful language. Just drag ImageView and make a try code,...."  Are we not mixing apple and orange!

Answer (score 7):

Besides Nitin Alabur's answer, a useful tip here:

UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell has a .selected property. If you put an UIImageView in a cell, then, when you select the cell, the imageView will use the .highlightedImage instead of .image.

Thus you can make cell selection visual state easily.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted image is for when you have a control that has a `UIImageView` that can be pressed. While the user is pressing the control, the highlighted image is shown. When the control is not being pressed, the normal image is shown.

Comment: UIImageView don't like imageView in UIButton. highlighted is a state  control by code or select in IB.

Comment: Not about the UIImageView but very contextual - To add to this, you can leverage UILabel's `highlightedTextColor` property in conjugation with cell selection. I find this very clean.

Answer (score -15):

All commenters have been wrong or answered the wrong question or been too wordy. Here's the simple and correct answer:

The highlighted image state is when the user's finger is touching the imageview.

Comment: Ironically, you're wrong.  UIImageViews don't react to touch events explicitly like a UIButton.

Comment: Yes. Technically you are correct. But the questioner is clearly looking for a simple answer. The simple answer is that the image becomes highlighted when a user is touching it.

Comment: Then try it yourself.  UIImageViews do not keep track of state like UIButtons.  They are static entities that are not part of the responder chain unless you ask them to be, and they certainly don't respect touch events without custom handler methods.

Comment: My experience (albeit as a student) has been that you always should implement a handler method for touch events to avoid unexpected behavior. Maybe I'm wrong in that regard and the best practice is not to always have handler methods, but that's a different problem.

Comment: You don't seem to understand: You mentioned that at it's simplest, highlighted means that the user is touching the UIImageView.  Not so.  The fact that you have to implement a handler makes this answer wrong.